# Find the latest date of two tables with matching primary keys

Tags: sql

I have two tables tables, each with primary keys for different people and the contact dates in each category.I am trying to find the most recent contact date for each person, regardless of what table its in. For example:

CustomerService columns: CustomerKey, DateContacted
CustomerOutreach columns: CustomerKey, DateContacted

And I'm just trying to find the very latest date for each person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like this.

You need to combine the two tables.  You can do this by a union.  There will be duplicates, but you just group by the customerKey and then find the Max DateContacted

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP FROM (
SELECT 
    CustomerKey
    , DateContacted
FROM CustomerService CS
UNION
SELECT 
    CustomerKey
    , DateContacted
FROM CustomerOutreach CS
)


SELECT
    CustomerKey
    , MAX(DateContacted)
FROM #TEMP
GROUP BY
    CustomerKey
```

Comment: pretty close Mike - but you could also just jam it all in one query - no temp

Answer (score 2):

Join your tables on primary keys and make a conditional projection.

```
  Select cs.CustomerKey, 
         CASE WHEN cs.DateContacted  <= co.DateContacted   
                 THEN co.DateContacted  
                 ELSE cs.DateContacted END  
      from CustomerService cs inner join CustomerOutreach co
           on cs.CustomerKey = co.CustomerKey
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this.

```
Select b.customerKey, b.dateContacted
from (
  select a.customerKey, a.DateContacted, Row_Number() over (Partition by customerKey      order by DateContacted desc) as RN
  from (
    Select c.customerKey, 
     case when (s.DateContacted > o.dateContacted) then s.dateContacted else o.datecontacted end as DateContacted
    from Customer c
    left outer join customerService s on c.customerKey = s.customerKey
    left outer join customerOutreach o on c.customerKey = s.customerKey
    where s.customerKey is not null or o.customerKey is not null
  )a
)b
where b.RN = 1
```

This solution should take care of preventing the case of having duplicates if both tables have the same max DateContacted.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca968/1

Comment: Note that this also takes care of handling if a customer is in one table but not in the other. I wasn't sure if that was a requirement.